# Dual Booting with 2 HDDs & Syslinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, bootloader

I've recently installed Arch linux and I'm using Syslinux as my bootloader. I'm using the following option to attempt to boot Windows on a **separate** disk to the disk Syslinux is on.

```
LABEL windows
    COM32 chain.c32
    APPEND hd1 0
```

However, this isn't working because when I select Windows, it just loads the Syslinux loader again.

This should work, I have these disks:

```
Arch Disk  Primary Master (HDD-0)
Windows    Primary Slave (HDD-1)
```

And the Windows Disk has only one partition; the one Windows is on..

I know I've missed something simple so could someone please help a noob?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Syslinux counts hard drives starting from 0 and partitions starting from 1.

```
LABEL windows
    COM32 chain.c32
    APPEND hd1 1
```

Also, if the COM32 chain.c32 doesn't work, try using KERNEL chain.c32 instead.